# Bootstrap Active Button in btn-group with ID

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a button group:

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <button id="specialOne" type="button" class="btn  "data-toggle="button">Item1</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn  "data-toggle="button">Item2</button>
</div>
```

Could someone be so kindly help me figure out how to use: 
`$('.btn-group button').removeClass('active');` 
to toggle off and i presume the opposite is `addClass('active')` 
however how apply it to a specific id button only i.e. button with ID specialOne?
`$('.id specialOne').addClass('active');`?

Updated:
See code at http://jsfiddle.net/Km4bj/

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the documentation for ID Selection](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$('.btn-group button#specialOne')
```

Should get you the specific button you want

I updated your fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cZfPE/5)

A few things, you didn't have Jquery added to the fiddle.

The other issue was that the JS functions you have bound to the onclicks up in your html weren't defined, so they were throwing JS errors and preventing further JS from running. Once I stubbed out the functions, that cleared out the errors and it's working.

So that's what you need to check in your actual page, whichever browser you are using for testing, you need to use the js console and check if errors are being thrown.

Comment: Hi thanks, read the documentation and it should work but its not :-(
$('.btn-group button#Hungover').addClass('active');

Comment: Odd - there's an onClick on my button can that cause problems??

Comment: Please edit the original question with the actual code you are trying to use so we can debug it.

Comment: I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cZfPE/5/

A few things, you didn't have Jquery added to the fiddle. The other issue was that the JS functions you have bound to the onclicks up in your html weren't defined, so they were throwing JS errors and preventing further JS from running. Once I stubbed out the functions, that cleared out the errors and it's working.

So that's what you need to check in your actual page, whichever browser you are using for testing, you need to use the js console and check if errors are being thrown.

Comment: Thanks! Found the entire issue - I had teh script in a div rather than outside and in the body